# How to provide one interface for retrieving and updating key,value?

Tags: c#

I am working on implementing a persistence layer for our application and have come up with a design where I have a provider that lets the client update single key,value and then I also have a transaction class via which I can update multiple key,value pairs.

The interfaces are:

```
public interface IStorageProvider
{
    bool GetValue<T>(string key, out T value);    
    T GetOrCreateValue<T>(string key) where T : new();    
    bool SetValue<T>(string key, T value);

    ITransaction Transaction();
}

public interface ITransaction : IDisposable
{
    event EventHandler<TransactionEventArgs> CommitSucceeded;
    event EventHandler<TransactionEventArgs> CommitFailed;

    bool GetValue<T>(string key, out T value);
    bool SetValue<T>(string key, T value);
    void Commit();
}
```

I don't like how provider and transaction have similar APIs like the `GetValue` and `SetValue`.

I would like that to be one interface and `IStorageProvider` and `ITransaction` deriving from that. What would you guys recommend ?

Comment: All values are `boolean`?

Comment: @ErikPhilips nope. Not sure why would you ask that ?

Comment: I miss read your interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you opened this thread more to get a confirmation rather than not knowing what to do. Of course it is okay to make a common interface for those methods, I don't see a reason why not to, as long as you put it in the correct project and find an appropriate name.

Comment: I was thinking to have something like `IKeyValueAccessor` and then let `IStorageProvider` and `ITransaction` to derive from it.

Comment: @Monku that is a very suitable name, I have to admit! And of course that you will have `IStorageProvider` and `ITransaction` *implement* it. This is why I called it a *common* interface. It is a normal practice in OOP these days, look for example at [IList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, @Monku that's why we're here.